# Angular: How to assigne value to variable in specific component from input of different template

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, datepicker

I'm making daterangepicker as Angular Component that is wrapper of JS library (https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). My problem is that I don't know how to pass value that is in input of datepicker to variable that is in other component (that where I want to use my daterangepicker). This is how I made daterangepicker component:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import 'bootstrap-datepicker';
declare var $;


@Component({
    selector: 'cb-daterangepicker',
    templateUrl: './daterangepicker.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./daterangepicker.component.scss']
})
export class DaterangepickerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    @Input()
    datepickerOptions: DatepickerOptions;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {

        $('.input-daterange').datepicker(this.datepickerOptions).on('changeDate', function() {
            var startDate =$('#start').datepicker('getDate');
            var endDate= $('#end').datepicker('getDate');
            console.log(startDate + " to " + endDate);
        });
    }
}
```

And the template looks like this:

```
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="start" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="end" />
</div>
```

Maybe I did something wrong but console.log returns me correct values so I think this two things are good.

What I want to achive:
In other component - let me name it 'exampleComponent' I have two variables: startDate and endDate, I need to pass values that I chose in daterangepicker to this variables every time I change the value. What I suppose to do?

Comment: I think the consuming component should use the datepicker in an Angular form. You may need to have the datepicker implement ControlValueAccessor: https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

Comment: Ok I implemented this but what next? I'm using directive in other component html and daterangepickerOptions to pass them in directive. But what about this two fields startDate and endDate in exampleComponent?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use @Output decorator,

First create new property in class DaterangepickerComponent mark it as @Output and assign EventEmitter Instance to it (you need import it)

```
@Output dateOutput = new EventEmitter<Object>();
```

Next in your callback when you have

```
console.log(startDate + " to " + endDate);
```

You need to use:

```
this.dateOutput.emit({startDate, endDate});
```

When you use your component you need to pass callback attribute to it

```
<cb-daterangepicker dateOutput="callback($event)">
```

after that when you choose date in datepicker callback method will be called